# Symfony 2 assetic wrong path with use_controllers: false

Tags: symfony, path, controllers, assetic

I tried to set use_controllers to false in debug mode, because on my machine, it takes 5 to 15 seconds, then I Generated the assets manually.

The generated files are fine, but when I open a page in my browser, no css or js files gets loaded. I took a look in the developer tools, and saw, that symfony is trying to load the files from "localhost/_controller/js/08f6dbe_jquery-1.7.2.min_1.js". If I remove the "_controller" in the path manually it works fine, but I have no idea, why symfony generate the     wrong path.

Some code:

```
#config_dev.yml

assetic:
use_controller: false
```

base.html.twig

```
{% javascripts '../app/Resources/public/js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I hope your can help me, and sorry for bad english

Comment: Just to check, is your use_controller line in config_dev.yml spaced in 2 spaces and not directly below assetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set output="js/*.js" in your twig tpl

```
{% javascripts 
    '../app/Resources/public/js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' output='js/*.js'
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

This should generate something like this - "//localhost/js/f31e898_jquery_.js"
you can replace the * with an actual name 'jquery' for example but to avoid caching it's beter to use the *.

hope this helps

Answer (score 12):

It just had to do with clearing your dev cache. I had the same thing happen to me when changing the configuration, but you need to manually do app/console cache:clear for your dev environment. It will not work on a simple page refresh.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem, but it fixed after clearing the cache

`php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: Thanks! I ran `rm -rf app/cache/dev` and it helped me. This answer should be accepted instead of current one proposing wrong `output="js/*.js"`